# map to derived type of destination in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to specify a mapping so that all mappings from "Source" to "Destination" is returned as a derived class of "Destination"

```
    [Test]
    public void Map_SourceToDestinationAsDerivedType_ReturnsDerivedType()
    {
        // arrange
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .CreateAs<ActualDestination>() // psedu code
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Transformed, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Property));

        var source = new Source{Property = "hi mom" };

        // act
        var destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

        // assert
        Assert.That(destination, Is.InstanceOf<ActualDestination>());
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string Property { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {

    }

    public class ActualDestination : Destination
    {
        public string Transformed { get; set; }            
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a map for the derived type `Mapper.CreateMap<Source, ActualDestination>()` and use that in the mapping: `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ActualDestination>(source);`?

Comment: Do you really think I would ask a question if that was the case?

Comment: This is not supported by Automapper the closest what you can get is writing something like :             `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, ActualDestination>()
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Transformed, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Property));
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                      .ConstructUsing((Source s) => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ActualDestination>(s));`

Comment: Thanks, write it up as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ok, fine but I sill don't undestand why don't you just write `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ActualDestination>(source);`? Even with my "solution" you still only can map every `Source` instance to a `ActualDestination` so why do you want to use the derived type in the mapping?

Comment: I have a list of classes derived from "Base" which should be mapped to a list of classes derived from class "Dst". Mapper.Map<List<Dst>>(src)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly supported by Automapper

However the closest what you can get is to define a mapper for the `Source, ActualDestination` pair

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, ActualDestination>() 
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Transformed, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Property));
```

And then use the `ConstructUsing` option in the `Source, Destination` mapping to do the translation from the `Source` to the `ActualDestination`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ConstructUsing((Source s) => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ActualDestination>(s));
```

Comment: Sidenote: In the ForMember you should use `MapFrom` instead of the `ResolveUsing` `.ForMember(dst => dst.Transformed, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Property));`